# How to interact with AMD GPUs using python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, amd-gpu

I want to interact with my AMD Radeon RX 580 using python.
Basic stuff that I want to accomplish:

1. Get power levels (How many watts is it pulling)
2. Set fan speed
3. Retrieve some info from the GPU itself like : Memory size, SubVendor (Saphhire, XFX etc), GPU and memory clocks, Memory type etc

I was looking for some way to get this info via python on "Windows".

I searched quite a bit but all the solutions seem to be avaible on linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install pyadl to find some infomations for amd gpu.
https://github.com/nicolargo/pyadl

```
>>> from pyadl import *
>>> 
>>> device = ADLManager.getInstance().getDevices()
...
>>> device.getCurrentCoreVoltage()
...
>>> device.getCurrentEngineClock()
...
>>> device.getCurrentFanSpeed(speedType)
...
```

Comment: Yes it has a lot of things I required, but the WMIC route seems more flexible to query additional info.Although its more a roundabout way to get info. I will wait for a few more days if any better solutions comes by which could directly talk to the gpu.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import os
os.system("cmd \k wmic path Win32_VideoController")
```

It shows some information. So you can extract them by modifying get parameter of CMD command.

```
wmic path Win32_VideoController get name
```

Command supports following get params :

> AcceleratorCapabilities  AdapterCompatibility  AdapterDACType  AdapterRAM  Availability  CapabilityDescriptions  Caption                    ColorTableEntries  ConfigManagerErrorCode  ConfigManagerUserConfig  CreationClassName      CurrentBitsPerPixel  CurrentHorizontalResolution  CurrentNumberOfColors  CurrentNumberOfColumns  CurrentNumberOfRows  CurrentRefreshRate  CurrentScanMode  CurrentVerticalResolution  Description                DeviceID          DeviceSpecificPens  DitherType  DriverDate                 DriverVersion  ErrorCleared  ErrorDescription  ICMIntent  ICMMethod  InfFilename  InfSection    InstallDate  InstalledDisplayDrivers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                LastErrorCode  MaxMemorySupported  MaxNumberControlled  MaxRefreshRate  MinRefreshRate  Monochrome  Name                       NumberOfColorPlanes  NumberOfVideoPages  PNPDeviceID                                                   PowerManagementCapabilities  PowerManagementSupported  ProtocolSupported  ReservedSystemPaletteEntries  SpecificationVersion  Status  StatusInfo  SystemCreationClassName  SystemName       SystemPaletteEntries  TimeOfLastReset  VideoArchitecture  VideoMemoryType  VideoMode  VideoModeDescription            VideoProcessor

Comment: This seems very promising